# Can Commerce be setup to skip Cart/Customer

Tags: commerce

Can the module Drupal Commerce (7.x-1.7) be setup so that a user can just click 'Buy' on an item and then be taken to a payment processor such as Paypal to pay? I've tried to find a way to do this but the Commerce set of modules is just a little overwhelming at the moment. 
I need to be able to do this as I'm selling a virtual currency to my users and they are used to a quick process and they don't wish to give out billing information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible but would need testing out and tinkering.

You could disable the checkout pages, other than payment / offsite payment redirect

Either at

- *admin/commerce/config/checkout* by setting the panes to disabled
- or perhaps with [hook_commerce_checkout_page_info_alter](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!commerce!modules!checkout!commerce_checkout.api.php/function/hook_commerce_checkout_page_info_alter/7) and removing the pages.

You could then add a Rule

- *Event: After adding product to cart*
- *Action: Redirect to page "checkout"*

Which will hopefully take the user off to PayPal / offsite payment.

Again, needs testing, but theoretically possible.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to take a look at the Pay module (https://drupal.org/project/pay) as I think Commerce may be too complex for my needs